# MarkLogic Database connection with Jasper server

Tags: marklogic, jasperserver

I want to create Jasper reports by fetching data from MarkLogic Database.
Unfortunately, MarkLogic Database doesn't have JDBC Driver, so someone help me in creating MarkLogic JDBC or JNDI connection in Jasper server.

Comment: Hi.   You replied to my post with  bit of detail. Someone else is now asking what version of ML you are using.  Perhaps it will be helpful for you to elaborate on your question. More detail about the server version, how you set things up, the specific error messages, etc all bundled into the question may give the right person a much better idea of how to assist.

Answer (score 2):

MarkLogic 8 has an ODBC driver. There is no JDBC/JNDI connector or bridge anymore from what I understand (and what was there in previous versions, I am not sure).

The ODBC driver can be downloaded here: https://developer.marklogic.com/products/odbc

Furthermore, the discussion on the bottom of that page also sheds some light on the subject (See comments from Steve Buxton and Thijs van Ulden)

Comment: Hi David - Thanks for the reply. I've tried setting ODBC connection successfully in windows but I am unable to connect to mark logic database from Jasper server using JDBC-ODBC bridge with following configuration:                                                                JDBC Driver: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
JDBC URL: jdbc:odbc:marklogic

Comment: Are you using Java 7?  JDBC-ODBC Bridge is still there in Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html

Comment: Hi Sam- I've tried with Java 7 connecting to Mark logic database using JDBC-ODBC bridge but I am facing this exception:net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.sql.SQLException: 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default 
driver specified